# Procedural elements references in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to make a mission display page, which display each mission summary into a row of a table, and if you click on one of the row, it expands the row which show the mission details.

Because the number of mission isn't static, I have to use procedural logic to display all of them (it's just getting into a `for` loop, nothing too spectacular.)

However, because of procedural logic, I can't really make some static identifiers for my rows as it goes through a loop, and I need to know on which row I'm clicking to know what to expand.

What should I do to identify which row I'm clicking on ? I'm accepting any solutions, either with only C# or by JS Interop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the object to the `onclick` event handler

```cs
@foreach(var item in items)
{
   <tr @onclick="() => OnRowClicked(item)">
...
   </tr>
}
@code {
   private void OnRowClicked(Item item)
   {
      Expand(item);
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I came up with a solution a bit similar using a `Dictionary<Item,bool>` to keep track of which row got clicked or not. It's working flawlessly, thanks for your indications.